# nodemon app.js throws error spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am getting the below error whenever I run nodemon app.js. I have Node.js 7.4.0 and npm 4.1.2 already installed globally and nodemon 6.7.0 as well. If I run my application using command "node" it works fine but if I use command "nodemon" it throws this error.

I tried to uninstall and re-install nodemon but wtih no difference.

The path for npm has been already added to system variables and "C:\Windows\System32" has been added to both user and system variables.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

```
events.js:160
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: spawn C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

Comment: application package.json: {
  "name": "my-example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.5",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "mongodb": "2.2.21",
    "mongoose": "4.7.7",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.0-beta6",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "stylus": "0.54.5"
  }
}